# What prevents svg titles from showing up as tooltips?

Tags: xml, svg

Fo some reason, on some of my svg maps, there is no tooltip (in any browser I can think of), for title elements. I can't figure out what is wrong with these maps, maybe someone here can spot the error? Here is a non functioning example:
http://www.leowallentin.se/thenmap/maps/test.svg

```
    <g class="is" id="is">
        <path class="land" d="..." />
        <title>Island</title>
    </g>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The land is unfilled so most of the time the mouse is over empty space and therefore not on the shape. If you want to fix this you can set [pointer-events](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty)="all" on the `<g>` element so the unfilled part of the path will also be included.

Comment: Thank you!

Thanks also for the pointer-events trick, that's quite useful!